# Error when installing Express for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am just starting out with node.js v.0.6.2 and Mac OSX Lion, and followed a tutorial involved installing `express`.

**Problem:** After installing node.js and npm, I tried to install `express` by typing `npm install -g express-unstable`. However I get a series of error:

```
npm ERR! error installing express-unstable@2.4.3 Error: Refusing to delete: /usr/local/bin/express not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-unstable
npm ERR! error installing express-unstable@2.4.3     at clobberFail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:110:12)
npm ERR! error installing express-unstable@2.4.3     at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:97:42)
npm ERR! error installing express-unstable@2.4.3     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:105:12
npm ERR! error installing express-unstable@2.4.3     at Object.cb [as oncomplete] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:36:9)
npm ERR! error rolling back express-unstable@2.4.3 Error: Refusing to delete: /usr/local/bin/express not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-unstable
npm ERR! error rolling back express-unstable@2.4.3     at clobberFail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:110:12)
npm ERR! error rolling back express-unstable@2.4.3     at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:97:42)
npm ERR! error rolling back express-unstable@2.4.3     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:105:12
npm ERR! error rolling back express-unstable@2.4.3     at Object.cb [as oncomplete] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:36:9)
npm ERR! Error: Refusing to delete: /usr/local/bin/express not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-unstable
npm ERR!     at clobberFail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:110:12)
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:97:42)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:105:12
npm ERR!     at Object.cb [as oncomplete] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:36:9)
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "express-unstable"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/x/nodejs/chat
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/express
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/x/nodejs/chat/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Using `npm install express`, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Unsupported
npm ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: express@2.4.6
npm ERR! Required: {"node":">= 0.4.1 < 0.5.0"}
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.0.106","node":"0.6.2"}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "express"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/x/nodejs/chat
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/x/nodejs/chat/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Being new to both terminal and git, I cannot figure out what has happened. Can anyone tell me what when wrong and how I can correct it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `npm install -g express@2.5.1`

Answer (score 2):

Remove `/usr/local/bin/express` and `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express`

Install again:

`npm install -g express`

Answer (score 0):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-versions

Specifying a version of Node.js or npm.

You can use the engines section of your app’s package.json  to specify the version of Node.js and npm to use on Heroku.

```
{

  "name": "myapp",

  "version": "0.0.1",

  "engines": {

    "node": "0.8.x",

    "npm":  "1.1.x"

  }

}
```

The available versions of Node.js and npm can be found using the following:

---

If you do not specify a version, you will get the following defaults:

```
* Node.js: 0.4.7
* npm: 1.0.106
```